# Differential transistor stage current not changing with temperature

Tags: current-measurement, temperature, differential-amplifier, biasing

I asked similar question recently, which also referred to differential transistor pair, but this one is different.

I made this circuit (in real world):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW6plI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I was only experimenting with DC (no signal applied). Potentiometer was used to adjust I_e1 to equal I_e2. Beta of transistors were around 300 and both of I_e were set to be exactly 1.1 mA.

After everything was connected as shown, I started to observe the I_e of each transistor when one transistor gets heated up. So, I "touched" the Q1 with two fingers for a few seconds - but nothing happened (no changes in current), same happened with the Q2. It seemed a bit strange that nothing happens. Then I took my lighter and heated one transistor to temperature about 100 degree Celsius - the current through both of transistor didn't even blink! At the end I really really heated it up - and only at this level of heating, the currents moved up/down the scale for 4-6 uA (micro amps)!

- How is this even possible? When lighter was usually approached, the I_e changed on the scale of mA, if not tens of mA.

I even replaced transistors - same results!

I also reconnected the whole circuit again - same results!

At the end I used different multimeter (in case one wouldn't work properly) - same results!

*This thing could be possible with current mirrors at collectors and constant current source at emitters, but I only used usual passive resistors.

Comparison of multimeter values:

[image]   [image]

Comment: The voltage at the Q2 base is around 11V. And if Ic1 and Ic2 is 1.1mA and Rc are 10k your BJT's are at the edge of saturation or in a saturation region. So, try to change Rc resistors value to 4.7k

Comment: @G36 Yes, you are right. But I don't understand why were both BJT's in saturation.. Aren't the Rc resistors calculated as V_Rc/I_e and then Re is calculated as V_Re/2*I_e ?

Comment: @G36 Oh sorry, I messed it up in the voltage divider - Voltage across R1 should be only around 6V; according to calculations, and R2 should be 10.7V. Actually R1 should be 19.3V instead of 6V.

Comment: Yep, your base voltage is too high or you have chosen the too large V_Rc value in your calculations. For Rc = 10k and Ic = 1.1mA you will get V_Rc = 10.1V. And the base voltage is around 11V so the BJT is clearly in the saturation region.

Comment: @G36 Hey, one more thing. Why do you think is important that voltage drop across Re or constant current source should be pretty large (not like only 1V as it is usually used in normal emitter degeneration)?

Comment: @Keno It's because it acts more like a current source (which is what you really want there) with more compliance voltage available to it. The more, the better current source it is. To see why, imagine you have a load that varies from \$1-1000\:\Omega\$ and you hook it up to a "current source" made out of \$1\:\textrm{MV}\$ (mega) voltage source and a \$1\:\textrm{G}\Omega\$ series resistor to your grounded load. What's the current variation over your load variation? Not much. Same situation now, except  \$10\:\textrm{V}\$ source and \$10\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$ series resistor. Now how good is it?